# rsync not overwriting newer files

Tags: rsync

### Replication details:

```
mkdir test && cd test
mkdir folder && cd folder

echo "#line1" > file
rsync -a -I . ..
echo "#line2" >> ../file
rsync -a -I . ..
```

### Output:

Content of `../file` is unexpected as it should've been overwritten
from the above rsync command. It should show just `#line1`

```
more ../file
#line1
#line2

more file  # <-- expected because we haven't edited this file
#line1
```

### Question:

I want the file to be overwritten always, is there something I've done wrong above?

### System info:

Rsync versions tried:

`rsync  version 3.0.4  protocol version 30`

and

`rsync version 2.6.9 protocol version 29`

OS tried:

```
SUSE Enterprise
Linux 3.0.101-71.1.10543.0.PTF.974263.72.1.csc-default x86_64
KDE 4.3.5
```

and

```
Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a Mac running 2.6.9.

Comment: What does it say if you use the `-vv` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that its a very stupid problem where there's an alias set with the `-u` flag in place already.

I just have to run `\rsync -a . ..` to escape the alias.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work as expected on version 3.0.6, I would check for an updated rsync in your repositories.

```
[user@server ~]$ mkdir test && cd test
[user@server test]$ mkdir folder && cd folder
[user@server folder]$ 
[user@server folder]$ echo "#line1" > file
[user@server folder]$ rsync -a -I . ..
[user@server folder]$ echo "#line2" >> ../file
[user@server folder]$ rsync -a -I . ..
[user@server folder]$ cat ../file 
#line1
[user@server folder]$ cat file 
#line1
```

#### Rsync Info

```
[user@server folder]$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30
```

#### System Info

```
CentOS 6.7 final
Linux server 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:19:08 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Running CentOS 7 with rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30,
I followed the steps and got the correct result.

Nothing is wrong with these steps, as they work for me. 
Possibly try running them again without the `-I` option, though.

```
➜ /tmp$  mkdir test && cd test
➜ test$  mkdir folder && cd folder
➜ folder$  echo "#line1" > file
➜ folder$  cat file 
#line1
➜ folder$  rsync -a -I . ..
➜ folder$  ls ..
file  folder
➜ folder$  cat ../file 
#line1
➜ folder$  echo "#line2" >> ../file
➜ folder$  cat ../file             
#line1
#line2
➜ folder$  rsync -a -I . ..        
➜ folder$  cat ../file     
#line1
➜ folder$  rsync --version
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
```